# Iframe Vimeo video end screen button action change

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, vimeo, vimeo-player

I have added the end screen as a call to action for the Vimeo video. I want to open one popup when clicked on the button on the end screen of the video.

[image]

By default if someone clicks on "CLICK HERE" button, the user will get redirected to some url.

I want to overwrite this action. I want to open one popup when the user clicks on "CLICK HERE" button.

I know how to overwrite the action. But I am not able to access the button from iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
console.log("Hello tehtere new");
  jQuery('iframe').contents().find(".vp-outro-button").click(function(){      
                console.log("Hello tehtere");
                alert('clicked img');
            });
});
</script>
```

I am getting below error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://somedomain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Because of security model of browser you're prevented from accessing items in iframes from other domains. [Same origin-policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) prevents you from doing this.

If vimeo supports callbacks outside of iframe, you could do it, but this is something that needs to be supported by vimeo.